# Can we make the entire flag area clickable in the flag dialog?

Tags: feature-request, support, flags

With the current layout, I often end up clicking between the radio button and the description. Can we make the entire area clickable?

In the image, pink areas are not clickable, blue are.

- The top example, "not an answer", is how it currently is. The radio button and description are wrapped in a `<label>` which is set to `display: inline`.
- The second example, "very low quality", is simply setting the `<label>` to `display: block`. This gives more space and eliminates the gap between the radio button and the description.
- The final example, "invalid flag", is making the entire `<li>` clickable. This gives a little more space around the left and top of the radio button, which is nice.

> [image: flag dialog]